# ASP.Net with Google app login

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am developing my web application in ASP.Net, and providing the option to login with Google App ID .
I did successfully created my `Client_ID` with Google and able to login with Google App.
I want to now access the user profile (`Google Email_ID , First Name , Last Name` ) .
But Google is returning the `URI` as :
`demo.aspx#state=/profileaccess_token=ya29.AHES6ZSv7tTdP7mXhdPLGq_4NvHFdHRhy9qmOnsFC0UNtr9uy4g`
and because of the "`#`" which should be "`?`", I am not able to retrieve the `access_token` from my code behind.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: have you used this.. http://openid-provider.appspot.com/ in your application for Google Login?

Comment: I am using the instructions ...  https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2